# Error Using Ajax when I load from a differente file with Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Im using **`JaxaScript(Jquery with Ajax)`** and my **HTML Page** all in the same file, but when I tried to code my **JS** and **HTML** in different files, I get an error when trying to **`ajax`** with **`Django`**.

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    value = $(this).data("forloopcounter");
    value = value - 1

    let variation_id = document.getElementsByClassName("select-variations")[value].attributes[2].nodeValue
    console.log(variation_id)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{% url "cart:add" %}',
        data: {
            variationid: variation_id,
            productquantity: 1,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function (json) {
            document.getElementById("cart-quantity").innerHTML = json.quantity
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
})
```

> `Note:` I have a guess it's because of this  `url: '{% url "cart:add" %}',`  but I don't know how to fix.

> `Note:` when I ajax with all in the same page it works.
>
> `Note` it's not an importation error, when i execute `console.log` it
> works

Error I get in the web:
`jquery.min.js:4          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20url%20%22cart:add%22%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)

HTML:

```
{% for variation in product.variation_set.all%}
                                   
                                    {%if forloop.first%}
                                    <!--pra fazer ajax passando id da variação selecionado(não aparece pra usuário)-->
                                    <small id="select-variations1" class="small select-variations"
                                        value="{{variation.id}}"></small>
                                    {%endif%}
                                    {%endfor%}`
```

Comment: so, you see what the URL currently IS, but what SHOULD it be?

Comment: http/127.0.0.1:800/cart/add

Comment: so put that there instead

Comment: Tried it, with url: 'http//127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add/', I got:  jquery.min.js:4          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/http//127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add/ 404 (Not Found)

and with  url: 'cart/add/',   I got error:  jquery.min.js:4          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add/ 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: well of course `127.0.0.1:8000/http//127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add`  is rubbish

Comment: I know, read the rest of the comment, i just tried just to show i did everything

Comment: with url: 'cart/add/', I got error: jquery.min.js:4 POST 127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add 403 (Forbidden) –

Comment: then you need to figure out what the correct url is

Comment: it's the correct url :   path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),     path("add/", views.CartAdd, name='add'),

Comment: a URL is a **string** - what you're showing is not

Comment: im showing the path which is literally how the route is built with django which means its namesite/cart/add

Comment: sure, but what does it actually look like in the browser

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues Can you also share your `html` code, i think the line `let variation_id = document.getElementsByClassName("select-variations")[value].attributes[2].nodeValue` is causing some problem?

Comment: I guess its working just fine, but i will share

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues Where is `#add-button` element in the html code on which the event is being fired? One more thing can you tell to me is you are getting this error of 404 Post request not found internal server error, only random times or every time? That means Every time you are getting error, or occasionally can you please check it, I also faced this problem, but I am not sure how do I implement it here.

Comment: Can you share that html part correctly where there is `#add-button` element?